# Change Image jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am not new to jQuery, however this should work and isnt:

html:

```
<a href='<?=$s['url'];?>' class='playbutton'><img src='http://i.domain.net/icons/play.png' width=20></a>
```

jquery `$("a.playbutton").click()`:

```
$(this).find("img").attr("src","http://i.domain.net/icons/stop.png");
```

If I change the `attr` to `addClass("jimbo")` I get the class jimbo added to my image.  So it is finding the img tag fine, but not changing the source.  Can someone tell me why?

full jquery function is:

```
$("a.playbutton").click(function(e) {
    var current = $("#jplayer").data().jPlayer.status.src
    var playing = current.split("/");
    var href = encodeURIComponent($(this).attr("href"));

    if(playing[3] != href) {
        $("#jplayer").jPlayer("setMedia", {mp3: "http://mp3.domain.net/" + href});
        $("#jplayer").jPlayer("play");

        $(this).find("img").attr("src","http://i.domain.net/icons/stop.png");

        $("a.playbutton > img").each(function () {
            $(this).attr("src","http://i.domain.net/icons/play.png");       
        });
    } else {
        $("#jplayer").jPlayer("stop");
        $("#jplayer").jPlayer("clearMedia");
    }
    return false;
});
```

All works fine apart from `$(this).find("img").attr..` line.  Like i said, If i change `attr` to addClass, it adds the class fine.  Meaning that it can find the correct `<img>` tag okay.

(URLs have been changed to domain.net)

Comment: change `attr` to `prop` :)

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using? [This](http://jsfiddle.net/jabark/D72Mv/) is working for me

Comment: How did you write your click function? 
Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/8hkF9/

Comment: @user3008011 it should be working fine, thats the problem! I must be missing something obvious.

Comment: @JamieBarker I am using 2.0.3

Comment: Is the image src perhaps added dynamically? If so, rewrite your `click` function to `.on('click' , function()`

Comment: @Chud37
Did my suggestion solve your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use prop in place of attr

```
$(this).find("img").prop("src","url");
```

Comment: `prop()` is used for boolean properties. `attr()` is fine for the `src` of an `img`. Even better would be to just use `.find('img')[0].src = "url"`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've forgot to add the return false to the callback, check this out:
http://jsfiddle.net/YnT5L/1/

```
$("a.playbutton").click(function() {
    $(this).find("img").attr("src","http://i.domain.net/icons/stop.png");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I was already returning false in my function, I've updated my question :)